# How can change broken file permissions of Time Machine backups?

Tags: macos, time-machine

My MacBook Pro needed repair so I backed it up using Time Machine and erased my data before bringing it to an Apple Store.

Meanwhile, I purchased a temporary MacBook Air to keep working. I then used SuperDuper! to create a bootable backup from which I could quickly restore my data on my MacBook Pro when it came back from repair which I did (wanted to do a clean install for a while vs TM restore).

For context, I could access my Time Machine backups on the MacBook Air, but now I can’t access some folders on my MacBook Pro (they have red circles with a white dash in them).

My current username is `sunknudsen` with uid `502`. It used to be `501` before the clean install (same username).

```
whoami
sunknudsen
```

```
id -u
502
```

```
ls -l /Volumes/G-DRIVE\ USB/Backups.backupdb/Sun’s\ MacBook\ Pro/2019-07-15-144502/Macintosh\ HD/Users/sunknudsen
total 16
drwxr-xr-x@  3 501  staff   102 21 Jun 15:41 Creative Cloud Files
drwx------+ 26 501  staff   884  6 Jun 08:59 Documents
drwx------+ 89 501  staff  3026 10 Jul 14:00 Library
drwx------+  8 501  staff   272 30 Apr  2017 Movies
drwx------+  8 501  staff   272  7 Feb 21:55 Music
drwx------+ 26 501  staff   884 12 Jun 15:00 Pictures
drwxr-xr-x@  4 501  staff   136  3 Jul  2015 Public
drwxr-xr-x@ 21 501  staff   714 11 Jul 10:45 Sites
drwxr-xr-x@  5 501  staff   170 21 Dec  2018 Software
drwx------+  7 501  staff   238 10 Jul 11:31 VirtualBox VMs
-rw-r--r--@ 15 501  staff  3134 24 Jan 11:06 sunknudsen.asc
```

So the folders in question have the wrong uid... how can I change their owner to `502`?

Tried `chown -R sunknudsen:wheel` but getting "Operation not permitted".

Using macOS Mojave. Thanks!

Comment: Who is user 501 on the new machine

Comment: I believe user 501 does not exist on the clean install (it has been deleted).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, this might break Time Machine so only follow these steps if you don’t plan on inheriting the backup on the new computer (my MacBook Pro in the above use case).

**Step 1.** Navigate to a folder with broken file permissions in a terminal as root (let’s call the folder `Things`).

```
sudo bash
cd /Volumes/G-DRIVE\ USB/Backups.backupdb/Sun’s\ MacBook\ Pro/2019-07-15-144502/Macintosh\ HD/Users/sunknudsen/Things
```

**Step 2.** Press enter. (If the `cd` command fails, you probably need to enable `Full Disk Access` for your terminal, I use iTerm).

[image: Full Disk Access]

**Step 3.** Once in the folder with broken file permissions (confirm you are in the right folder by running `pwd`), run the following command.

```
sudo find . -user 501 -exec sudo chmod -h -N {} \; -exec sudo chown -h `whoami` {} \; -exec sudo chmod -h +a "group:everyone deny add_file,delete,add_subdirectory,delete_child,writeattr,writeextattr,chown" {} \;
```

`sudo find . -user 501` will find all files owned by user with uid `501` in the current folder.

`-exec sudo chmod -h -N {} \;` is the secret sauce. It will [remove](https://ss64.com/osx/chmod.html) [access-control list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access-control_list) (ACL) rules which prevent us from running a familiar `` chown -R `whoami` . `` command to change file ownership.

`` -exec sudo chown -h `whoami` {} \; `` will change the ownership of the files found by `find` to the [user who is running the command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whoami).

`-exec sudo chmod -h +a "group:everyone deny add_file,delete,add_subdirectory,delete_child,writeattr,writeextattr,chown" {} \;` will restore the default Time Machine ACL rules (which is optional).

**You should now have access to the `Things` folder!**

Comment: I ran into this issue when I had a MacBook repaired with a photos library on an external disk. Instead of going through all this, since the library has multiple folders, I simply copy the folder. The copied folder has the permissions I need. Annoyingly, when trying to open a Photos library with this issue, Photos simply says it tried to do a repair but wasn't able to. Not very helpful.

Comment: On macOS Catalina, I get the error "**Operation not permitted**"... I think this error is depended on the command `sudo chmod -h -N {} \;`