# TimeMachine - Unable to access backups from old MacBook due to UID change

Tags: time-machine, permission

OS Version: MacOS Ventura 13.2

I got a new MacBook and before I sold my previous MacBook, I created a backup through TM.

Now on the new MacBook I wanted to access the backup of my previous MacBook and faced 'Permissions denied' issues. Digging around, I found out that my previous MacBook had only 1 user (UID 501) and my new MacBook already has two users and personal one has UID 502.
I already tried out to use the first user to access the backup and it works - But that's not a long-term solution.

EDIT: The new machine was brand-new. There is one account with id 501 and another account (which is my personal account) with id 502. The first account with id 501 is intentional and must stay as is.

Found [How can change broken file permissions of Time Machine backups?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/365062/how-can-change-broken-file-permissions-of-time-machine-backups) and tried to align that to the APFS formatted TM HDD. Unfortunately without success - While I could do the changes in `/Volumes/USB_DRIVE_NAME/2023-02-06-162553.previous/` I've seen later that the TM backups are mounted *read-only* in `/Volumes/.timemachine/SOME_UUID/2023-02-06-162553.backup` and this is where the TM browser reads from.

Is there any way to fix the permissions for my old TM backup so I can access it again? Maybe somehow possible to mount the `2023-02-06-162553.backup` read-write?

Comment: By the way, restoring the new MacBook from the old backup is not an option either

Comment: Is the new machine new new, or just new to you (pre-owned but not properly initialised)? Normally if it were a brand new OS install there would only be one user, you, and that UID would be 501. If your UID on your account is 502, then there is an existing user (501), hence the question re. the machine's provenance. I wouldn't try to change the ownership of your backups of the old machine. Try an OS reinstall on the new machine first before trying to restore.

Comment: The new machine was brand-new. There is one account with id 501 and another account (which is my personal account) with id 502.
The first account with id 501 is intentional and must stay as is.

Comment: Understood. Please update the question so the info doesn't get lost in the comments.

Comment: Thanks Andy, I updated the post

Comment: I would be alarmed if the backups were mounted read/write.  Don't mess with them or you will likely lose them. Continue to use 501 to access the old backups when needed. And start again with TM on a new disk.

Comment: I got the same backup on another HDD, so it's fine to try out on one HDD. I can only get temporary access to 501, so it's not an option to continue accessing the old backup with 501. Agree that backups shouldn't be mounted read/write by default, however I would still like to have the opportunity to decide for myself (and especially in this case this is one way to fix the permissions that comes to my mind).